# Tensorflow RNN cells have different weights

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to write a simple RNN in tensorflow, based on the tutorial here: https://danijar.com/introduction-to-recurrent-networks-in-tensorflow/
(I'm using a simple RNN cell rather than GRU, and not using dropout).

I'm confused because the different RNN cells in my sequence appear to be being assigned separate weights. If I run the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf

seq_length = 3
n_h = 100   # Number of hidden units
n_x = 26    # Size of input layer
n_y = 26    # Size of output layer

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, seq_length, n_x])

cells = []
for _ in range(seq_length):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(n_h)
    cells.append(cell)
multi_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)

initial_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_h])

outputs_h, output_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_rnn_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print('Trainable variables:')
for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    print(v)
```

If I run this in python 3, I get the following output:

```
Trainable variables:
<tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(126, 100) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(100,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(200, 100) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(100,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(200, 100) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_2/basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(100,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Firstly, this isn't what I want - an RNN needs to have the same weights from input-to-hidden and hidden-to-hidden at each layer!

Secondly, I don't really understand *why* I get all these separate variables. If I look at the [source code for rnn cells](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py) it looks like BasicRNNCell should call `_linear`, which should look up whether there's a variable with name `_WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME` (which is set globally to `"kernel"`), and use it if so. I don't understand how `"kernel"` gets decorated to `"rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0"`.

If anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to distinguish two different things: the number of layers of your recurrent neural network and the number of time this RNN gets unrolled by the Back Propagation Through Time algorithm to handle sequence length.

In your code:

- The `MultiCellRNN` is taking care of creating a 3 layers RNN (you are creating three LAYERS there, and MultiCellRNN is only a wrapper to make easier to deal with them)
- The `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` is taking care of unrolling this three layered network for a number of times related to your sequence length

Comment: I understand now! Thanks for that - it's blindingly obvious now that you've pointed it out.